# Table: how to include a picture, spanning 9 rows

Tags: tables

I need to include a picture in the first column of this table, spanning all the 9 rows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell,multirow}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}



\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{|*{2}{>{\bfseries}c|}
             *{2}{>{\bfseries}c}|}
\hline
\rowcolor{blue!10}
            &   &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{GPS-Koordinaten}}    \\
\rowcolor{blue!10}
\multirow{-2}*{Situation}  
      &  \multirow{-2}*[-0.2ex]{\makecell{Punkt Nr.}}
                &   \makecell{Rechtswert [m]}    
                    &   \makecell{Hochwert [m]}          \\
\hline
& 1   &   8427590.000 & 4476960.000  \\
\hline
& 2   &   8427570.000 & 4477120.000  \\
\hline
\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{Map.jpg}} &  3   & 8427572.000 & 4477120.000  \\
\hline
& 4   & 8427574.000 & 4477123.000  \\
\hline
& 5   & 8427576.000 & 4477126.000  \\
\hline
& 6   & 8427578.000 & 4477129.000  \\
\hline
& 7   & 8427580.000 & 4477132.000  \\
\hline
& 8   & 8427582.000 & 4477135.000  \\
\hline
& 9   & 8427584.000 & 4477120.000  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I feel that \hline, as I used it in this code, is not correct, because of the first row, where a picture should be included. How can I change this and how can I include a picture which is spanning those 9 rows just in column 1?

What I get is this:

[image]

using this image:

[image]

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: You can use  `\cline{2-6}` instead of `\hline`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution consists in using the first column of the table, using the optional arguments of `\raisebox` to fool LaTeX and make it believe the image has  height and depth equal to `0`, and using `\cline{1-4}` instead of `\hline`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell,multirow}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}



\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{|*{2}{>{\bfseries}c|}
             *{2}{>{\bfseries}c}|}
\hline
\rowcolor{blue!10}
            & & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{GPS-Koordinaten}} \\
\rowcolor{blue!10}
\multirow{-2}*{Situation}
      & \multirow{-2}*[-0.2ex]{\makecell{Punkt Nr.}}
                & \makecell{Rechtswert [m]}
                    & \makecell{Hochwert [m]} \\
\hline
& 1 & 8427590.000 & 4476960.000 \\
\cline{2-4}
& 2 & 8427570.000 & 4477120.000 \\
\cline{2-4}
\raisebox{-.7\height}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{ernst_vierge}} & 3 & 8427572.000 & 4477120.000 \\
\cline{2-4}
& 4 & 8427574.000 & 4477123.000 \\
\cline{2-4}
& 5 & 8427576.000 & 4477126.000 \\
\cline{2-4}
& 6 & 8427578.000 & 4477129.000 \\
\cline{2-4}
& 7 & 8427580.000 & 4477132.000 \\
\cline{2-4}
& 8 & 8427582.000 & 4477135.000 \\
\cline{2-4}
& 9 & 8427584.000 & 4477120.000 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would use a three column tabular next to the image, but if you want to have a single tabular you can do as follows. I'd also avoid boldface.

Don't forget the `p` positional argument for such a big table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\bfseries

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|cc|}
\hline
\rowcolor{blue!10}
Situation & Punkt Nr. & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{GPS-Koordinaten}} \\
\rowcolor{blue!10}
          &           & Rechtswert [m] & Hochwert [m] \\
\hline
\multirow{9}{*}{\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth,height=5cm]{example-image-9x16}}
& 1   &   8427590.000 & 4476960.000  \\
\cline{2-4}
& 2   &   8427570.000 & 4477120.000  \\
\cline{2-4}
&  3   & 8427572.000 & 4477120.000  \\
\cline{2-4}
& 4   & 8427574.000 & 4477123.000  \\
\cline{2-4}
& 5   & 8427576.000 & 4477126.000  \\
\cline{2-4}
& 6   & 8427578.000 & 4477129.000  \\
\cline{2-4}
& 7   & 8427580.000 & 4477132.000  \\
\cline{2-4}
& 8   & 8427582.000 & 4477135.000  \\
\cline{2-4}
& 9   & 8427584.000 & 4477120.000  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]